# PHP json_encode return unescaped '

Tags: javascript, php, json

I experience the problem with parsing json encoded object in js. 
`JSON.parse(word_array);` with error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

My investigation showed that object `word_array` does not exist because of wrong-formation in PHP: it has a unescaped single quote`'` inside, thus making js consider it as the end of the string.

I form encoding next way:

```
echo "<script>var word_array = '";
echo  json_encode($word_set);
echo "';\n";
```

As far as I know, json_encode should escape all undesirable charactets like `'` but it does not.
What might be the problem?

My php version: `Version PHP: 5.3.13`
And `$word_set` is array of assoc. array:

```
$word_set = array();
while($stmt->fetch())
{
  $word_set_tmp[] = array(
    'word' => $word, 
    'definition' => $def
  );
  array_push ($word_set,$word_set_tmp);
}
```

Comment: Please show the output of json_encode, showing the claimed unescaped quote

Comment: Why would you assign string and then parse it when you could assign json right away (without wrapping it in quotes).

Comment: I cut the end (as it is big).
`var word_array = '[{"word":"Abeyance","definition":"a temporary suspension of activity."},{"word":"Akimbo","definition":"having one's hands in a bent position on the hips."}`

Comment: The problem in `one's`

Comment: @Cthulhu funny thing: your suggestion fixes his issue too, as afaik `'` shouldnt be escaped

Comment: Anyway, JSON specifies that single quote be escaped only when encoder is using single quoted strings, so it is a valid json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you surrounding an array declaration in single quotes, remove them and all is well:

```
echo "<script>var word_array = " . json_encode($word_set) . ";";
```

As a side note, i find when i must mix php with anything else (html, js) then its best to exit php mode and write html/js, echoing out the required php vars, rather than echo out html/js:

```
<?php 
    $word_set = $db->somfunc();
?>
<script>
    var word_array="<?php echo json_encode($word_set);?>";
    alert(word_array[1].definition);
</script>
```